# Static and media urls in Django

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-media, django-static

In my settings file there is `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` and getting access to static files(css files) from the directory `app/static/css/filename` . If I add this to the setting file
`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` is it possible to access the media files from `app/media/filename`? There is no `MEDIA_ROOT` or `STATIC_ROOT` in my settings.py.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MEDIA_URL` is meant for files uploaded by a user. These files are not checked in, so you shouldn't have a `media` directory inside your app.

For media files to work, you must set `MEDIA_ROOT` in your settings. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) for instructions how to serve media files.

Comment: then why getting the static files?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. To [deploy static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-the-site-and-your-static-files-from-the-same-server), you need to set `STATIC_ROOT` and run `collectstatic` to copy files to the root. However in development, Django the [staticfiles app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) will serve files in your `app/static/` directory for you.

Comment: Bro my static root is not set still  getting the css (static files ).

Comment: As I said, if you are in development (`DEBUG = True`), then you don't need to set `STATIC_ROOT`.